# Windows 8 Store App: Registering client for push notification results in "access is denied" on remote server only

Tags: wcf, push-notification, windows-store-apps

When I attempt to register a windows store app for push notification I receive the "Access is denied" error when the remote server is running authorization on the client's SID and client secret.

NOTE:
1. This only occurs on the remote server. 
2. I do NOT receive this error when running this service locally.
3. I checked the web config and did not identify anything out of the ordinary.
4. I'm using WCF
5. I just purchased some SSL certificate and applied it to the server.

Do I need to wait for this recently installed SSL certificate to take effect?

Please help...

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: No... I receive push notifications on my tablet from other Windows 8 apps.